# Angular - Fire $http.get on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My home page is loading and then firing my $http.get() request after the page is already loaded.

How can I get the request to fire first **before** the page loads, so I can use the returned data on the page?

Routing:

```
var leisureApp = angular.module('leisureApp', ["ngRoute"]);

leisureApp.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            .when("/home", {
                templateUrl: "Scripts/HTML/Home.html",
                controller: "HomeController"
            })
            .when("/login", {
                templateUrl: "Scripts/HTML/Login.html",
                controller: "LoginController"
            })
            .when("/time", {
                templateUrl: "Scripts/HTML/Time.html"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/home"
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: true,
            requireBase: false
        });
    }]);
```

HomeController:

```
angular.module('leisureApp')

    .controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'ADAuth', function ($scope, ADAuth) {

        $scope.ADAuth = ADAuth;

    }])


    .factory('ADAuth', function ($http) {
        return $http.get('Home/GetUser');
    })
```

MVC Controller method:

```
public JsonResult GetUser()
{
    var user = new LeisureUser();
    user.ActiveDirectoryName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
    return new JsonResult { Data = user, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: try using the $http.get('Home/GetUser'); in the controller itself rather than making a factory for it

Comment: as mentioned by @JesseCarter, you can use `resolve:` to resolve a promise.  However, it may not be necessary, and in your case, your issue is that you aren't ever invoking  `()` your service, only assigning it, so the `$http` is never actually called at all.  also, `$http` returns a promise, and you'll need to use `.then()` to access the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [resolve](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx). It allows you to make a route dependent on a function value or promise which you then inject into your controller and will be available at controller instantiation.

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/news", {
        templateUrl: "newsView.html",
        controller: "newsController",
        resolve: {
            message: function(messageService){
                return messageService.getMessage();
            }
        }
    });

app.controller("newsController", function (message) {
    $scope.message = message;
});
```

Note that the property name of the resolve object `message` matches the value being injected into your controller. If you're using array syntax for min-safe code it would be something like this:

```
app.controller("newsController", ['message', function (message) {
    $scope.message = message;
}]);
```